# Convert multiple currencies and total the results in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I have 4 currency columns (GBP, Euro, DKK, SKK). I then want to convert them to GBP in the 'Total Column. Is there a formula to look at all 4 currency columns and then convert to GBP in the specific exchange rate I enter?

```
Cell A | Cell B | Cell C | Cell D | Cell E 
GBP    | Euro   | DKK    | SKK    | (A/0, B/1.11, C/8.25, D/11.8)
```

Comment: Aside: A would be divided by 1 not by 0. The conversion factor from a currency to itself is 1.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`googlefinance`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) provides the current exchange rates for all these currencies. For example, this converts the amounts in A1, B1, C1, D1 from (GBP, EUR, DKK, SKK) to GBP, and adds them.

```
=A1 + B1*googlefinance("currency:EURGBP") 
    + C1*googlefinance("currency:DKKGBP") 
    + D1*googlefinance("currency:SKKGBP")
```